# Total Amount of Experience from 1 to 50

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

What is the total amount of experience required to level from 1 to 50 in Star Wars: The Old Republic?

Comment: I've asked it here because I couldn't find it on Google or other known sites and was curious. Further, I thought others might be as well. I was also curious about why this was down voted.

Comment: This question seems like a perfectly reasonable question, and I could not find the answer with a simple Google search. How is something a Google question vs a SE question anyway? Any on topic question is welcome on SE as long as it is clear, concise and not already covered.

Comment: your'e looking for legacy exp right?

Comment: This question is being [discussed on the meta-discussion site](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4614/what-the-heck).

Comment: Update: in Knights of the Fallen Empire (Patch 4.0), they changed the whole table.  Every level has different (lower, apparently) XP requirements.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The answer for experience required to reach level 50 is: **8,231,605**. This information was [gathered first hand](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0ArThhiNiW80bdDNYREJtN3g2NEV6Tlk2Wk5ib2pES1E) by myself and others leveling in my guild and server.

For legacy experience, [the answer is instead 20,564,000](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1W2tOHTOEtV0_Ag2kJuLWAwEH3jnc4SPiyqr1JUaeZPY/edit#gid=0).

Comment: I have played it, and I agree that it is 8,231,605.

Comment: I've made a spreadsheet, don't know if that is preferred to the archived page: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1W2tOHTOEtV0_Ag2kJuLWAwEH3jnc4SPiyqr1JUaeZPY

Comment: This is outdated with patch 4.0 (KotFE).  All the points for levels have changed for 1-50.  I can't say for legacy right now... I was too shocked to check when I realized this change for normal levels last night.